# Nouveau Error: unknown chipset during startup Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I'm using laptop Acer Nitro VN7-571G-53N6, nvidia GeForce 840M. This is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

```
[11.128989] nouveau E[DEVICE][0000:03:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x118010a2
[11.129037] nouveau E[   DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
```

Comment: Have you tried resetting the CMOS?

Comment: @gyropyge Could you please explain why you think that would fix the problem?

Comment: If you even have to ask, it means you've never seen just how corrupted a cmos can become.  The cmos stores a great deal of information that tells the computer how to behave.  Past a certain point of extreme corruption, it can tell a computer to misbehave rather severely.  You appear to be describing such a misbehaving computer.  Perhaps it would comfort you to imagine it is instead possessed by demons?  ---edit---  I mistakenly assumed the author of the post asked me this nonsense question.  I now realize the question comes from someone who may know a lot about Ubuntu but little about CMOS.

Comment: @gyropyge No offense, but trying to the reset the CMOS wouldn't be at the top position in my troubleshooting attempts when I see that a graphics driver couldn't detect the graphics chip. A laptop with a "graphics chip" from "2014" (assumed to be rebranded) also would prove to be difficult to get it's CMOS reset (not documented in the manual, not an action a customer should perform) which would result in accidentally resetting the NVRAM of the UEFI platform which stores keys for UEFI secure boot and links to EFI loaders on the hard disk to boot operating systems (read as trash OS installs).

Comment: @LiveWireBT, I will never understand why anyone continues to market any type of notebook computers as "gaming" pc's, but they do, and to the extent that they make them at all configurable, they actually install pretty much all of the tweakable settings in the BIOS of the computer which means that all the settings are saved in the CMOS.  Now, I don't claim to be remotely up to speed with the newest computers with their EFI issues, and so it is even possible that the computer in question doesn't have a handy "accept defaults" option.  Maybe it doesn't, but if it does, it probably wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @gyropyge That sounds more reasonable than finding a jumper or DIP switch on the PCB or temporarily removing a battery which may not even exist.

Comment: @LiveWireBT, Jumper?  DIP switch?  Did I suggest either?  No I did not.  This is a NOTEBOOK COMPUTER.  It probably doesn't have an actual "jumper" anywhere on it.  PS.  I've yet to disassemble/repair a laptop, notebook or netbook which doesn't have some sort of cmos battery.  Sometimes they are rechargeables, other times they are standard 2032 coin cells.  To date I've never encountered a laptop so compromised its battery needed to be disconnected to solve the problem but I suppose it is only a matter of time until that happens.

Comment: @gyropyge I know this is kind of old, but for the benefit of others who see this highly ranked page on Google, resetting the CMOS isn't on the list of things to do in debugging a problem like this. At all. Gaming laptops has nothing to do with this. Batteries have nothing to do with it either. The guy you pounce in that last comment even said "temporarily removing a battery which may not even exist" and you chose to ignore that and yell the same thing then essentially say "well nvm". Don't go around telling people to reset their laptop's CMOS with advanced NVRAM setups the norm.

Comment: Even by your own explanation, at best resetting the CMOS because an _open source alternative to proprietary drivers_ doesn't recognize a _new laptop GPU_ of all things is quackery, and you could end up putting a lot of people through a lot of pain for no reason with a comment like that.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see the open source driver in this release doesn't support this relatively new card.

Did this happen with the live session or an actual installation?

A [workaround](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219518&s=e2d8b31598f132b031900d93ec617138&p=13001836#post13001836) in these scenarios for installations seems to be:

- Rebooting in `recovery mode` via advanced options in GRUB.
- Setting graphics to `failsafeX`.
- Install the proprietary Nvidia drivers: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/q/61396/40581)

Please test the latest LTS and non-LTS ISO images (currently 14.04.01 and 14.10). If the issue still exists on the latest non-LTS, then please file a bug. Here is an example for an older card:

- [LP #1142733](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/1142733) - Nvidia: unknown chipset

Comment: I wonder in which package or system component this driver would be if it is updated. xserver-xorg-video-nouveau? Or in the Kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this error can be very misleading, while in most cases you get this after modifiyng UEFI settings and it has nothing to do with your nVidia chipset.
In many cases its caused by an NTFS partition which was not completely unmounted.
The solution can be turning the Fast startup off in Windows (http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html).